# Создание объектов класса в цикле

Tags: python, ооп

Всем привет! В процессе создания одного мини-проекта возник затупок по поводу создания объектов класса в цикле. Знаю, наверное это очень просто, но иногда я туплю на очень простых моментах. Если описывать задачу более детально, то в цикле надо создать какое любо количество объектов (например, 20) с разными именами (достаточно что бы просто отличался хотя бы один символ) какого либо класса (например, класса "Class_1"), на Python соответственно. Пожалуйста, не осуждайте меня, может я туплю из за того сейчас вечер и я немного уставший.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так

```python
class Student:
    name: str = None

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "Студент: " + self.name

    __repr__ = __str__


students = [Student(f"Студент_{i}") for i in range(20)]
print(students)
```

Если совсем просто, то вот:

```python
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


students = [Student(f"Студент_{i}") for i in range(20)]
for i in range(5):
    print(f"Объект_{i}: ", students[i])
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает! Только я не понял что значит "__repr__ = __str__". И еще синтаксис "name: str = None", раньше я не видел, что бы двоеточие использовалось в данных ситуациях. Попроще никак?\

Comment: Можно без всего этого. `__repr__` и `__str__`- магические методы, которые отвечают за строковое представление объекта. `: str` - это синтаксис аннотаций типов (рекомендую погуглить). Что-то типа статической типизации, но нет

Comment: Все равно непонятно. Написал такой код и он чет не работает:
```class Солдат:
    pass

солдаты = []

for i in range(20):
    солдаты.append(Солдат('солдат_{0}'.format(i)))```

Comment: Ваш класс имеет реализацию конструктора по умолчанию, это значит, что для создания объекта от класса `Солдат`, мы не должны передавать дополнительные параметры.

Comment: Но я и так не передаю дополнительные параметры.

Comment: `"солдат_{0}"` - лишний параметр для вашей реализации класса

Comment: ладно, спасибо, понятно

Comment: Слушай, а можно ты напишешь же без всех этих repr и str? Если с аннотациями я разобрался, этот момент понять не могу.

Comment: Изменил свой ответ, добавил совсем простой вариант

Comment: Теперь реал спс